# multiple copies of the same object that can be interacted with separately

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am trying to create multiple copies of the same display object with individual properties that can be accessed from anywhere. Particularly, I want to be able to tap and interact with each of them. My code so far is below:-

```lua
centerX = display.contentCenterX
centerY = display.contentCenterY

local function onGemTouch(event)
    print("to see if each object can be tapped")
end

local spawnTable = {}


local function gamebegin(params)

    ball = display.newImageRect(params.image, 62,62)
    ball.x = centerX - 4*60 +2*(params.x-1)*60
    ball.y = centerY -3*60 + (params.y-1)*60
    ball.ballTable = params.ballTable
    ball.index = #ball.ballTable+1
    ball.myName = ball.index
    ball.ballTable[ball.index] = ball

    return ball
end
--i have four images that I want to use randomly--

for i = 1, 4 do
    for j = 1,7 do
        local spawn = gamebegin({image = "images/" .. math.random(4)  ..".png", x=i, y = j, ballTable = spawnTable})
    end
end

ball.tap = onGemTouch
ball:addEventListener( "tap", ball )
```

The code works in the sense that there is no error and the copies apppear in the grid that I want but only the last copy of the object can be clicked. So obviously I am doing something wrong here.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing much else about your code (or Corona), I think the right syntax to add a listener is:

```lua
ball:addEventListener("tap", onGemTouch)
```

Since you want to add this to every ball, you either need it inside of the loop creating the balls, or you need it inside the function creating the ball. If we put it inside the function creating the ball, we get:

```lua
local function gamebegin(params)
    ball = display.newImageRect(params.image, 62,62)
    ...
    ball:addEventListener("tap", onGemTouch)
    ball.ballTable[ball.index] = ball

    return ball
end
```

Since `gamebegin` appears to be just creating a new ball, why not rename it to `addBall`? And if you're adding it to the `ballTable` and never using the return value, just don't return anything:

```lua
local function addBall(params)
    ball = display.newImageRect(params.image, 62,62)
    ball.x = centerX - 4*60 +2*(params.x-1)*60
    ball.y = centerY -3*60 + (params.y-1)*60
    ball.ballTable = params.ballTable
    ball.index = #ball.ballTable+1
    ball.myName = ball.index
    ball:addEventListener("tap", onGemTouch)

    ball.ballTable[ball.index] = ball
end

for i = 1, 4 do
    for j = 1,7 do
        addBall({
            image = "images/" .. math.random(4)  ..".png", 
            x=i, 
            y = j, 
            ballTable = spawnTable})
    end
end
```

Adding suggestions from my comments on your answer:

```lua
local centerX = display.contentCenterX
local centerY = display.contentCenterY
local offset = 60
local imageSideLength = 62
local spawnTable = {}

local function onGemTouch(event)
    print("to see if each object can be tapped")
end

local function getBall(imagePath, x, y)
    local ball = display.newImageRect(imagePath, imageSideLength, imageSideLength)
    ball.x = centerX - 4*offset + 2*(x - 1)*offset
    ball.y = centerY - 3*offset + (y - 1)*offset

    return ball
end

for i = 1, 4 do
    for j = 1, 7 do
        local ball = getBall("images/" .. math.random(4) .. ".png", i, j)
        ball:addEventListener("tap", onGemTouch)
        table.insert(spawnTable, ball)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply Millie. Your method might just work but I had stumbled upon another solution in the meantime

Turns out I needed to add addEventListener("tap", onGemTouch) to the spawnTable. But I'll try out your method - it seems easier.

Comment: You're welcome. In general, you should reply to me in a comment (I'm not sure if you have those privileges yet). One more note: usually you don't pass a collection (`spawnTable` in this case) to a function that creates an item for the collection. Generally you build the item (usually in a constructor, but at first glance I'm not sure if Lua has constructors), and then you return it from the function. Then you put the return value into the collection. Like `local ball = getNewBall(...); ballTable[nextIndex] = ball;`.

Comment: That way you don't need an `index` property on `ball`, and you don't need to reference the collection with a `ballTable` property on `ball`. The balls may move around in the collection anyway, and then all of the indices will be wrong unless you update them. And if they're part of more than one collection, `ballTable` means nothing. (Also not sure why you set the ballname to `index`)

Comment: Also, I hope I'm not annoying you, but if you put `local offset = 60` or something similar at the top, you can reference it when you set `ball.x` and `ball.y`. That way, if you want to change it to 50, you can change it in one place instead of four. And if you need that value in another function for some reason, it's available and it has a name that makes your code easier to read.

Comment: I added a complete rewrite at the end of my answer with these suggestions and a couple more (changed all the global variables to local, as global variables generally make programming harder, and I added some spacing for readability here and there).

Comment: Also changed `params` to `imagePath, x, y` because it makes the code more readable, and I moved all the variable declarations next to each other.